# Hosting on freeBSD

Tags: networking, apache-httpd

I already installed FreeBSD 10, Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5. I also just bought a domain from *GoDaddy*, and I would like to setup a web-hosting in my server, in order to make my website to be reachable from any web browser. So should be my configuration?

1. I assigned my server (running FreeBSD 10) the static IP address 192.168.1.130
2. My domain.com has x1.x1.x1.x1
3. My internet service provider is (ISP) is x2.x2.x2.x2

Questions:

- From these 3 IP addresses above, which one should my `httpd.conf` in *Apache 2.4* have to be listen to?
- In my DNS “A” record at *GoDaddy*, which IP address should my domain point to?
- Do I need to make any changes in my `/etc/hosts` file?

**Note**: I use x1.x1.x1.x1 and x2.x2.x2.x2 as examples.

Answer (score 2):

a) Apache will need to listen to 192.168.1.130.  There's no need to specify an address though, it can listen on all addresses.

b) Whichever of 2 or 3 is the IP address of *YOUR* connection (as in what shows up when you browse to http://www.whatsmyip.org/).

In addition:  No you do not need to touch /etc/hosts.

There's a huge piece here that you are missing however.  '192.168.1.130' is an internal (RFC 1918, not publicly routed) address.  The internet cannot talk to you at that address.  You need to set up a port forward from your router that will pass along the traffic destined for your public IP address to the internal 192.168.1.130.

If this isn't clear enough, please detail what the IP addresses of each is.  2 and 3 don't make much sense.  Not whom the IPs belong to, but what is at those IP addresses.  If I'm interpreting correctly #2 is simply the IP address that GoDaddy uses to show a landing page after you register a domain.  If correct, that IP is meaningless.  If #3 means something other than the IP address your ISP *assigned to you*, then you'll have to clarify what you mean there as well.

Comment: Hi @yoonix, Please correct me if I'm wrong,
I put this lines in Apache (httpd.conf):

Comment: `Listen 192.168.1.130:80`
`ServerAdmin my-email`
`ServerName my-domain.com`
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`
`AddType application/x-httpd-source .php`
`DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`

Comment: This is my IP address 72.255.215.235, the one from my ISP or what I see from http://www.whatsmyip.org/.

Comment: I’ve created a port forwarding to my internal IP address 192.168.1.130 with port 80 TCP.

Comment: And as you mentioned in your last paragraph, you were right, #2 was an interpretation of the IP address that GoDaddy provided me from the domain I got. And #3 also was my ISP IP address which I just clear mentioned above.

Comment: So, to create a DSN record, should I point to my ISP Ip address or my internal IP?

Comment: What else is missing? Sorry if my question isn't clear, it is my first time setting-up this.

Comment: You should create an `A` record in DNS pointing to 72.255.215.235. As for the httpd.conf you can have the Listen line be `Listen *:80`